# Python how to pivot table with custom criteria

Tags: python, pivot-table

- I have a problem with setting up custom index on my pivot_table function, I want the index label to be looped as much as I need (even though the dataset doesn't contain that observation)

- Data Sample

```
d = {'cat' : ['One','One','One','Two','Two'],
     'cha': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], 
     'fruit': ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Orange'], 
     'number': [7, 8, 12, 1, 11]}

data = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

- The Result I Want:

| Cat | Cha | Fruit | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Apple | 8 |
|  | A | Banana | 7 |
|  |  | Orange | 0 |
|  | ----- | -------- | ------- |
|  |  | Apple | 0 |
| One | B | Banana | 0 |
|  |  | Orange | 12 |
|  | ----- | -------- | ------- |
|  |  | Apple | 0 |
|  | C | Banana | 0 |
|  |  | Orange | 0 |
| ----- | ----- | -------- | ------- |
|  |  | Apple | 0 |
|  | A | Banana | 0 |
|  |  | Orange | 0 |
|  | ----- | -------- | ------- |
|  |  | Apple | 0 |
| Two | B | Banana | 1 |
|  |  | Orange | 0 |
|  | ----- | -------- | ------- |
|  |  | Apple | 0 |
|  | C | Banana | 0 |
|  |  | Orange | 11 |
| ----- | ----- | -------- | ------- |

- What my Python code (pd.pivot_table) return me so far (with index as Cat, Cha and Fruit; Number as Value):

```
data.pivot_table(
                          index = ['cat','cha','fruit'],
                          aggfunc = sum,
                          fill_value = 0)
data
```

| Cat | Cha | Fruit | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Apple | 8 |
| One | A | Banana | 7 |
|  | ----- | -------- | ------- |
|  | B | Orange | 12 |
| ----- | ----- | -------- | ------- |
| Two | B | Banana | 1 |
|  | ----- | -------- | ------- |
|  | C | Orange | 11 |
| ----- | ----- | -------- | ------- |

After this, is there another way to insert in a data column mapped as columns for this type of pivot_table?

I tried using reindex but with this much index I am not able to loop it all.